# Select columns from join table - TypeOrm

Tags: node.js, nested, typeorm

I have a join query like bellow and i'm trying to convert it to typeOrm query

```
SELECT a.actionName 
FROM walletAppActions wa 
INNER JOIN actions a on a.actionId = wa.actionId 
WHERE wa.appId = 1
```

**ActionConfig.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('actions')
export class WalletAppActionsEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
    actionId: number;  

    @Column()
    actionName: string;

    @OneToOne( type => Actions , config => config.action)
    config: Actions;
}
```

**appActions.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('walletAppActions')
export class Actions{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
    id: number;  

    @Column()
    appId: number;

    @Column()
    actionId: number;

    @OneToOne( type => WalletAppActionsEntity , action => action.config)
    action: WalletAppActionsEntity;

}
```

table structure has attached here

**walletAppActions table**

[image: walletAppActions]

**Actions table**

[image: actions]

Comment: You can use `find` with relations nah?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let data=await getManager().getRepository(WalletAppActionsEntity)
            .createQueryBuilder('wa')// where wa is alias
            .leftJoinAndSelect('actions','acti','wa.id = :id',{id:1})//acti is alias
            .getOne();
```